# Is it a good idea to store an Object in Amazon Dynamo as Json?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

After looking at Amazon DynamoDB I have been trying to figure out how to store my complex objects that I create in my code and want to persist.  I understand how I would store these objects in a Relational Database like MySql but how would I store them in DynamoDB?

I can think of one way....turn them into Json and store the Json representation of the Object in DynamoDB.  To get them out of  DynamoDB again I would marshall them back from Json to my Object representation in my code.

Here is an example:

For this type of Object:
A Car has an Engine Which has many Parts. Each Part has a Serial Number, a Life Span and a Replacement Value.
Now I can turn the Car into json which would look something like this:

```
{
    "engine": {
        "parts": [
            {
                "serialNumber": "1234",
                "lifeSpan": 10,
                "replacementValue": 100
            },
            {
                "serialNumber": "5678",
                "lifeSpan": 1,
                "replacementValue": 200
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Should I just store the above Json in Dynamo as Key: CarName 'Jaguar',  Value [above json] ?  Or is there a better way to store the Car Object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand how I would store these objects in a Relational Database
>   like MySql but how would I store them in DynamoDB?

The mainstream solution for DynamoDB is pretty similar to the MySql one: you just,
change a table row (mysql) with a table item (dynamodb), they both are flat structures,
but a dynamodb item could have different attributes from other items in the table, and 
have a [64KB item size limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html) (column/attribute names included).

> Should I just store the above Json in Dynamo as Key: CarName 'Jaguar',
>   Value [above json] ? Or is there a better way to store the Car Object?

No, once your parts array grows you will face the [64KB item size limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html). You can store a compressed version of the json to mitigate, but then you will not be able to use any attribute feature (eg. [LSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html) or [GSI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html), [updateItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html)) in dynamodb, nor integrate seamlessly with other AWS products.

You can take a look at the way [dyngodb](https://github.com/aaaristo/dyngodb) stores those objects, shortly: one dynamodb item, for every object. One hash for arrays, with N ranges for the array elements.

Comment: The item size limit has now increased to 400 KB

Comment: But the result size of a fetch (i.e. query or scan) is limited to 1MB. So, assuming you store 25 items of 400 KB, you would have 10MB, and would need to perform 10 paged fetches to retrieve the data from the database. And it could easily take 30 seconds to fetch those 25 items from the database.

Answer (score 2):

I think storing objects is fine, as long as you don't overdo it.

Some other responses mention that the **maximum size of an Item is 400KB**. **However, there is also a maximum size for the result of a fetch which is more problematic, since this limit is only 1MB.**

So, let's say you plan to store huge documents, and end up consuming 200KB per Item. If you put more than 5 items in your database, then you are over the 1MB limit. That means, if you plan to do a query that needs to return more than 5 items, it won't work. You will only get 5 items, and you will have to perform a 2nd query to get the remaining items. You will need to consolidate those yourself. On top of that, it will be slow.

**For small JSON messages that's not really an issue, and you shouldn't worry about it.**

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an array of strings / stringset. That way you can push in more items one by one, unfortunately you can't request only one item, you need to get them all. Another option is a serialized array (if you are using php) that turns a nice php array into a string for storage in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

The item size limit has been up to 400kb.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

So I don't think item size limitations should be as large of an issue now.

However, the issue regarding integration with other AWS service still stands. For example I'm fairly certain you can't use cloudsearch on these json mapped fields. Especially, considering you could store pointers to an S3 object as the field data if the data was too large.

I've used the map type in dynamo a bit and it is fairly handy/clean compared storing all the data in fields if you can live with the new limits. If you are using node/javascript the dynampdb datatypes library is critical to getting this stuff playing nice.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-data-types

Answer (score 1):

I don't know you are accessing your dynamo db programatically. Suppose if you are doing that, then probably below might help you.

1. Use the document model for doing any db operation with dynamo DB. If you are doing it in asp .net core then definitely document model is only chance.
2. On Dynamo Db the field/Column on which you want to store the json data. Select that **column type as Map**.
   Benefit of **Map type**  is that you can index the json data using key/value pair.

Regarding size limit map support 400kb.
check the below link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-data-types

Regarding document object model you can check this link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKMidLevel.html